# What is the board to board connector of CM4 to IO board?

Tags: hardware, compute-module, compute-module-4

I'm trying to draw a new board for hobby project that utilize the CM4 (Compute Module 4). However, I didn't found any footprint for the connector module of the board to board connector between CM4 and the IO board in KiCAD.

Any one knows what is the module, or where can I found the library that contains the module for KiCAD? Or any one has experience of where to look for such information?

Thanks!
W.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/compute-module.html#compute-module-4 ?  the CM4IO KiCad fle seems to have info on the hirose connector

Comment: Hey Dirk, Thanks! Yes, the design file of CM4IO contains a module of CM4 layout, that have the basic footprint and layout for the connector. However, I have difficulty to found out the element for BOM. But now, I've found what I'm looking for: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/hirose-electric-co-ltd/DF40C-100DS-0-4V-51/1969476